# functions within functions and calling main() using python

Tags: function, python-2.7

I have several functions such as

```
def plot_lines(...):

def plot_setup():

def BP4_avg(...):
```

which all work fine but when I add a calling function `main()` it breaks

```
def main():
    ...

    plot_setup()

    BP4_avg(...)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any ideas?

If I remove `main()` and just have

```
plot_setup()

BP4_avg(...)

plt.show()
```

program works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first version you're just defining the functions but you are not calling them - so everything works fine.

On the second version (the one with `main()` ) you are actually executing these functions and one of them breaks...

Comment: To be more clear the program works and I am calling the functions without the use of def main(): The moment I add def main(): to wrap the code I get errors, any ideas? I hope this is not going in circles.

Comment: @Lefti what is the error, from which line in the code does it get triggered ?

Comment: The problem was a variable was not being passed properly. It was not a problem when I did not have the def main(): block but adding it brought out the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lefti not a problem!